# Colorbox popup cancelled out by form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, colorbox

I have a colorbox that calls a PHP page depending on user input and database values. The problem is:

When I comment out the "document.getElementById(formID).submit();" below, the colorbox opens fine. When it is left in, or when the "return false" after the colorbox call is removed, then the colorbox only opens briefly with only white contents, then closes immediately.

This is definitely unrelated to the PHP page called by the colorbox because it works fine when the form submission won't take place (and the same colorbox call works fine in another function which does not involve a form submission). But I do need the form to be submitted when the customer clicks on OK!

```
function reactivate_customer_account (formID, user, server, wowzaStatus, kundenNummer) {

        var answer = confirm (unescape("Do you want to reactivate the user account?")); 

        if (!answer) return false;

        document.getElementById(formID).submit(); // this appears to cause the problem!

        if (wowzaStatus == 999) { 

            $.colorbox({ href: "https://webpageaddress.de/script.php?request=reactivate&user=" + user + "&server=" + server + "&KdNr=" + kundenNummer, iframe: true, width: 450 + "px", height: 700 + "px", transition: "fade" });
            return false;

        }  

    }
```

The code by which this function is called:

```
<form id='kunden_reaktivieren_form_{$row['id']}' method='post' action='' onsubmit='return reactivate_customer_account(\"kunden_reaktivieren_form_{$row['id']}\", \"{$row['FTP_download_benutzername']}\", \"$kunden_server_name\", \"{$row['WowzaStatus']}\", {$row['Kundennummer']});'>

<input type='hidden' name='session_key' value='$session_key'/>
<input type='submit' value='Kunden AKTIVIEREN'/>
...
</form>
```

Grateful for any help and explanation what the issue is! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
document.getElementById(formID).submit();
```

your page will refresh and it will not execute the code below. If you want your colorbox to open, you should call form submission through AJAX.

jQuery `$.ajax` or `$.post` will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want the PHP page that is being called to open in a colorbox or some kind of popup? Can that be done through $.ajax or $.post?

Comment: yes that can be done. Call colorbox code once your response comes form the server through ajax. use onsuccess.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have the form submission after the colorbox call somehow? That would avoid all that extra effort? Or making it somehow separate, even though both form submission and colorbox call depend on the same button klick?).

Comment: if you call form submission(not ajax) after colorbox, the coorbox will open and immediately the page will refresh. then what is the use of colorbox opening. ajax submission is your only solution to show colorbox.